# C++ overload << and unary minus

Tags: c++, reference, operator-overloading

I have a strange error (no match for 'operator<<' in std::cout << BigReal::operator-()() )  when doing this:

```
cout<<(-D);
```

where << is overloaded as following:

```
ostream & operator<<( ostream &c, BigReal &n )
{
    c << n.nume << "=" << "[" << n.nr << "]  ";
    return c;
}
```

and unary - as:

```
BigReal BigReal::operator-( void )
{
    float negativ = atof( nr );

    char buff[ 1000 ];
    sprintf( buff, "%f", -negativ );

    //strcpy( nr, buff );
    BigReal Rez(buff, "Nr.");
    return Rez;
}
```

and D is a BigReal.

Comment: replace BigReal & by const BigReal & in your operator <<

Comment: `const const const const const const const`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expression -D creates a temporary object. A temporary object may be bound to const reference. So change operator << the following way

```
ostream & operator<<( ostream &c, const BigReal &n );
```